# update DB with datagridview enter event

Tags: c#, datagridview

1. I want to update my database when i click on a cell of my datagridview in fact i want to edit my database and datagridview by clicking on a cell.
2. And I have an id in my database that it's auto fill and when i insert and save s.th i need that id fill by my sql.and there are my codes that does not work :

code 1.

```
     private void dgvlist_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
       con.ConnectionString = "server=(local);database=tel;trusted_connection=yes;";
       con.Open();
       cmd.Connection = con;
       da.SelectCommand = cmd;
       DataGridViewCell cell = dgvlist.SelectedCells[0] as DataGridViewCell;
       string value = cell.Value.ToString();
       cmd.CommandText = ("update information set name =@name , family=@family , telephone=@telephone , mobile = @mobile where id = @id");
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", value);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", value);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@family", value);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", value);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile",  value);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
```

code 2.

```
    private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtname.Text == null || txtfamily.Text == null || txttel.Text == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please fill the neccessary boxes");
        }
        else
        {
            save();
        }
    }
    void save()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        con.ConnectionString = "server=(local);database=tel;trusted_connection=yes;";
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        cmd.CommandText = ("insert into information id = @id , name =@name , family=@family , telephone=@telephone , mobile = @mobile where id = @id");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@family", txtfamily.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", txttel.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", txtmobile.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: at first question my program works but when i click on a cells and fill them no changes happen to database

Comment: and the second when i click save button i have this sql error : An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'id'.

Comment: it's important for me to have the ability to edit when i click on a cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple Answer**

1. `DataGridView.Enter` is only triggered when the `DataGridView` receives focus and is entered; not when you enter a new cell. Also, changes haven't been madeuntil after you've already entered the cells. Lastly, your update probably fails because `where id = @id` isn't evaluating to `True` when you think it should.
2. Your sql Insert statement is incorrectly formatted, as the error states: "*Incorrect syntax*".

**Deeper Explanation**

Let's assume you have the following database setup:

```
+---+-------+--------+-----------+----------+
|id | name  | family | telephone | mobile   |
+---+-------+--------+-----------+----------+
|1  | John  | Smith  | 123-4567  | 123-4560 |
|2  | Jane  | Doe    | 987-6543  | 987-6540 |
|3  | Jenny | Tutone | 867-5309  | 867-5309 |
+---+-------+--------+-----------+----------+
```

And your resulting `DataGridView`:

[image: DataGridView Image containing equivalent data to mocked database]

---

Now suppose we misspelled John Smith's name, which should be *Jon* instead. Assuming some other control has focus at the time, you click on the cell in row 0 column 1 - your method is now triggered (*before* any changes are made):

> ```
>     DataGridViewCell cell = dgvlist.SelectedCells[0] as DataGridViewCell;
>     string value = cell.Value.ToString();
>     cmd.CommandText = ("update information set name =@name , family=@family , telephone=@telephone , mobile = @mobile where id = @id");
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", value);
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", value);
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@family", value);
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", value);
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile",  value);
> ```

Effectively, the query that is being run is:

```
update information set name ='John' , family='John' , telephone='John' , mobile = 'John' where id = 'John'
```

Since there are no records `where id = 'John'`, no records are updated. On the other hand, had you instead first clicked on the cell in row 0 column 0, your query would have looked liked:

```
update information set name ='1' , family='1' , telephone='1' , mobile = '1' where id = '1'
```

Which would result in the following database changes:

```
+---+-------+--------+-----------+----------+
|id | name  | family | telephone | mobile   |
+---+-------+--------+-----------+----------+
|1  | 1     | 1      | 1         | 1        |
|2  | Jane  | Doe    | 987-6543  | 987-6540 |
|3  | Jenny | Tutone | 867-5309  | 867-5309 |
+---+-------+--------+-----------+----------+
```

Therefore, you need to fix which values you set in your command parameters. Then you should consider moving this updating code to a different method, such as `DataGridView.CellEndEdit`, so that it's updated after any changes are made in the current cell.

---

As for your insert statement, a simple google search would have shown the correct format. Change the following:

```
cmd.CommandText = ("insert into information id = @id , name =@name , family=@family , telephone=@telephone , mobile = @mobile where id = @id");
```

To the following:

```
cmd.CommandText = ("insert into information (name, family, telephone, mobile) values (@name, @family, @telephone, @mobile)");
```

There should be no need to add the `id` into the statement as it should be an identity column in your database and will be auto-generated.